# Importing a google font via CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to use a google font in my website. I've used this before:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantata+One);
 #MasterHeaderWrap .TopNav .rtsLevel1 .rtsLink .rtsTxt { font-family: 'Cantata One', serif !important; text-transform: uppercase !important;}
```

And it worked to change the font. The correct font was displaying. However, when I try to use the same format for this font:

```
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo);
 #MasterHeaderWrap .TopNav .rtsLevel1 .rtsLink .rtsTxt { font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif !important; text-transform: uppercase !important;}
```

It's not displaying properly. I mean the font changes, but it's definitely not Exo. Can anyone advise?

Just as a disclaimer here, I don't have access to the HTML backend, I only have access to a CSS editor on the website, so all I can do is plug in these css snippets.

Edit: I got it! All I had to do was rearrange my code. Thank you guys! You're all magicians in my book!

Comment: Get rid of those `!important` rules.

Comment: If I don't have the !important rules there the entire thing doesn't change :/

Comment: Then it means there are other important rules that are overriding your CSS. Can you locate those? What happens if you do just: `font-family: 'Exo' !important;` ?

Comment: I've got it. All I had to do was rearrange my code! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo);

#MasterHeaderWrap .TopNav .rtsLevel1 .rtsLink .rtsTxt {
    font-family: 'Exo Regular', sans-serif !important; text-transform: uppercase !important;
  /*------------------^^^^^^^ */
}
```

### EDIT

Well, I think you have your website through HTTP, so the request to google fonts needs to be HTTP and not HTTPS, so this works:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo);
/* ------------^^*/
#MasterHeaderWrap .TopNav .rtsLevel1 .rtsLink .rtsTxt {
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif !important; text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

Comment: No go unfortunately. :(

Comment: I make a test and it works. You seem to have something more wrong.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure...I literally just copy and pasted what you wrote :(

Comment: Yeah, but maybe you have another code that causes conflict with that. I don't know. The code as is on this post is perfect and runs Ok. You can make your own test on https://jsfiddle.net for example.

Comment: Hey I got it. I had a bunch of CSS code and all I had to do was rearrange it!

Comment: Remember that @import sentences needs to be the first sentences on the css file, if you put a comment before that doesn't work. Check the answer as correct when you can. Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, I checked it as correct. Could you just really quick show me how to increase the font size that I've imported?

Comment: That's another question, but you can set font size on `html` tag: `html { font-size: 62.5%; }` > with this setting you can use `rem` and `em` units with decimal base (1em == 10px)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo');
```

Comment: No go, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the snippet below, this should work fine:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo);

 #MasterHeaderWrap, .TopNav, .rtsLevel1, .rtsLink, .rtsTxt {
   font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

body { padding: 20px; } /* Reset Styling */
```

```html
<div id="MasterHeaderWrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam molestiae eos earum sint. Debitis libero quam, atque ducimus inventore ut, quo non quasi autem repellat commodi dolores. Dolor, nulla, commodi?</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Saurav! Thanks a lot for your help. That's actually the same code I'm using and it doesn't work. I'm really not sure why...

Comment: @lolikols Can you post a jsFiddle or a Codepen link to show exactly what's happening?

Comment: Hey I got it. I had a bunch of CSS code and all I had to do was rearrange it!